# How can I integrate a new system to a design scheme I previously created?

Tags: mysql, database-design, schema

This is a follow-up to a question I wrote a while ago, for reference, you can look it up [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/22336/designing-multiple-tables-while-eliminating-duplication).

I've developed a curriculum based database scheme that looks like this(Thanks [Joel Brown](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/3106/joel-brown))
[image]

Now that a new educational system is introduced(while the old one is still not "deprecated") I have been looking for a way to integrate both curriculum systems together without creating a whole new different system; As the two systems are fundamentally different, this have been quite a challenge for me.

Here's a picture describing the new system . . .

[image]

(English level 1, 2, and 3 are classified as *courses*)

See, the new system removes the whole grades system. A jr. high school student can enroll in the *exact* same course(English level 3, for example) as a sr. high school student.

Is there a way to make those two systems work with my current design scheme? Or should I create a whole new scheme for the new system?

Comment: Can you add the results of SHOW CREATE TABLE `table_name` for each of the tables that currently exist (and that apply to this question)?

Answer (score 1):

Would it not solve your problem to redefine the `GRADE_LEVEL` table such that it contains either the *grade* of a course or the *level* of the course (which ever applies)?

The rows in `GRADE_LEVEL` could contain values such as:

```
GRADE 7
GRADE 8
GRADE 9
GRADE 10
GRADE 11
GRADE 12
LEVEL 1
LEVEL 2
LEVEL 3
```

You might consider adding a partitioning attribute to the `GRADE_LEVEL` table that would indicate which educational system is being applied.  This may be helpful for some of your application logic that might need to apply different processing depending on which system is in use for a given `COURSE`.

Answer (score 0):

Pardon me if I have translated the question wrong. What I see here is the existing system is at a more granular level than the newer one. In the existing system `GradeLevel` and `Course` have a One-Many relation so courses can be retrieved by grade level and if I need to find all unique courses I will need to eliminate the grade level from my query. Yet `Course` table still holds unique list of courses available. Now in the new system there is no `GradeLevel` entity type. So the new system is less granular than older one.

[image]

I would translate above picture as new system. From the schema perspectve nothing is changed, it is just APIs accessing these tables. Creating a new set of APIs to use a new way to select/insert/update among these tables will require a good amount of code change as well to make sure code is calling the right set of APIs based on who the caller is and/or which API call is intended for which system, new or old.

Changing the existing APIs to select/update/insert based on data received by those APIs will not require much work on the code side. If `GradeLevel` information is requested or supplied then APIs will assume this is a request for/from old system otherwise it will behave for the new system.